# Transformation Method - Removing Resistors

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I'm trying to solve my teacher's shared example, but it says 'we begin by removing 125 ohm and 10 ohm resistors from the circuit'. I don't understand how we can remove them. Don't they have any effect?

[image: schematic]

Comment: They have no effect on the \$v_o\$ voltage as Andy's answer makes clear. However, for example, the 125Ω resistor dissipates 500W so they certainly have other effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't understand that how can we remove them? Doesn't them have any
> affect?*

- A resistor in parallel with a voltage source has no effect on Vo
- A resistor in series with a current source has no effect on Vo

Just simple basic rules you should remember. Does a resistor in parallel with a voltage source change the voltage produced by the source - NO. Does a resistor in series with a current source change the current produced by the source - NO.